# Non-optional to-many relationship allows nil or empty set

Tags: core-data

I have a sample data structure:
Table "Groups" and table "Items". Groups can contains zero or more items and item must be linked to minimum one or more groups:

```
Groups   |--------- to-many, optional ---------->>|Items
---------|<<------- to-many, non-optional! -------|--------
groupName|                                        |itemName
items    |                                        |groups
```

I create NSManagedObject subclasses. Both are trivial but here is Items:

```
class Items:NSManagedObject {
    @NSManaged var itemName:String
    @NSManaged var groups:Set<Groups> //attention: there is no ! or ?
}
```

In code below I expecting to catch error:

```
var item = Items()
item.itemName = "AAAA"
do {
    try Items.moc.save() //moc - static field in Items "linked" to ManagedObjectContext
}
catch {
    print(error)
}
```

But there is no errors! item saves to CoreData with empty groups. I can't figure out why? **But if I make Items to Groups relation non-optional to-one (in class Items groups field became @NSManaged var group:Groups) exception throws as I expected.**

I know, that I can implement in Items class function validateGroups, where I can check if groups nil or empty, but I want to know: is there my mistake that I cant find or it is Core Data bug (or feature)? More, I like to implement storage logic into database (in sql I very like triggers, I can't live without foreign keys, constraints etc).

So, please, help me to understand this. Thanks!

Comment: Did you set the minimum count of groups to 1?

Comment: Thank you, now it works! I thought, setting relationship to non-optional will be enough. My brains still can't switch from MySQL )

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved, thanks to Willeke!
When I set minimum count in Item's entity relation properties problem disappeared.

[image]